# Magento 2 single store mode still exports products for both store views?

Tags: magento2, data-migration

Why is a magento 2 site in single store mode still exporting products from global and store view stores?

These products were initially migrated using the `data-migration-tool` from magento 1

[image: Store View Export example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior.
Single store mode can be enabled if you only have 1 store view.
And this is a way to remove some store selection fields from different admin screens.
If you have 2 or more store views, the setting "single store mode" is ignored.
The result of the single store mode is determined in `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::isSingleStoreMode`.
the method looks like this:

```
public function isSingleStoreMode()
{
    return $this->isSingleStoreModeEnabled() && $this->hasSingleStore();
}
```

where `isSingleStoreModeEnabled` checks the config setting  and `hasSingleStore` checks `count($this->getStores(true)) < 3`.

Why 3?
Because the admin is considered a store. So this only works if you have one frontend store view and one admin store view.
summing up, in your case `isSingleStoreMode` will return `true & false` which evaluates to `false`.

Comment: `$this->isSingleStoreModeEnabled()`: true
`$this->hasSingleStore()`: true

Comment: Really? This is strange then

Comment: Yes, I think this is maybe an issue that was brought over from the previous magento store which had products duplicating for both the global and store view scope.

Comment: Or maybe that's how the export works.